# RoR extend ActiveRecord::relation with undestroy_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I basically want to the following function, but in the reverse, and i already have the `undestroy` function working for single classes.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2ad168ee41d590bd9a4d15eddf3c2f719c23b60a/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L364

However, I am trying to to extend ActiveRecord::Relation to no avail. Here's how i do it for other methods by for `ActiveRecord::Base`

`ActiveRecord::Base.extend Track::BaseTrack`

But using `ActiveRecord::Relation.extend Track::TrackRelation` doesn't seem to do anything. The module `TrackRelation` (inside `Track`) is:

```
  module TrackRelation

      def undestroy_all(conditions = nil)
        if conditions
          where(conditions).undestroy_all
        else
          to_a.each {|object| object.undestroy }.tap { reset }
        end
      end

  end
```

Am I using the correct ActiveRecord class for relations?

The error is:

`undefined method "undestroy_all" for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call `ActiveRecord::Relation.extend Track::TrackRelation` you are mixing the `Track::TrackRelation` methods into `ActiveRecord::Relation` as class methods.

What you want to do is mix in those same methods as instance methods. You can do that using `include` rather than `extend`. However `Module#include` is private. So one way to achieve what you want is:

```
ActiveRecord::Relation.send(:include, Track::TrackRelation)
```